# Boundary Flowout Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm trying to prove **Theorem 9.24 (Boundary Flowout Theorem)** from *John. M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* . There, all steps are like proving **Flowout Theorem** , but in last one, I just can show that ${\Phi|_o}_{\delta}$ is an injective smooth immersion, not an embedding
(We can't use Proposition 4.22(d) beacause of boundary in M).

Also there is a hint in ***Problem 9.11***  but I have no idea how to use it:

"define $\Phi$ first
in boundary coordinates and use uniqueness to glue together the local definitions.
To obtain an embedding, make sure $\delta(p)$ is no more than half of the
first time the integral curve starting at $p$ hits the boundary (if it ever does)."

Comment: Even if you gave some references (which I appreciate), the message in itself is missing some context. Could you elaborate a bit your question by stating the result you want to show, what are the assumptions, and what you tried, for example?

Comment: My apology. The state of problem and all asumptions  are in Lee's textbook and in there, I used the assumption of existing an global inward vector field to show that an integral curve starting from a point of boundary never intersects boundary again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem that you're asking how to prove is the following (rephrased from the book):

**Boundary Flowout Theorem:** *Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold with nonempty boundary and that $N$ is a smooth vector field over $M$ such that $N$ is inward-pointing at any point of the boundary $\partial M$. Then there exists a smooth positive function $\delta : \partial M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ and a smooth map $\Phi : \mathcal{P}_\delta\rightarrow M$, where
$$\mathcal{P}_\delta=\left\{ \left(t,p \right) : p\in\partial M\ \ 0\le t<\delta \left(p \right)\right\},$$
such that $\Phi$ is a smooth embedding onto an open neighborhood of $\partial M$ that satisfies the following property: for any $p\in\partial M$, the curve $t\mapsto\Phi \left(t,p \right)$ for $0\le t<\delta \left(p \right)$ is the integral curve of $N$ starting at $p$.*

You should follow the first half of the hint given in the book, which is done as follows:

1.) Choose boundary coordinates $ \left(U,\varphi \right)$ of $M$.

2.) Push $N$ down the image of $\varphi$ to $\mathbb{H}^n$ to get $\hat{N}=\varphi_\ast N$, and then extend that smoothly to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Call that smoothly extended vector field ${\hat{N}}_E$ ("$E$ " for "extension").

3.) Then use the flow of ${\hat{N}}_E$ to construct a local version of $\Phi$.

4.) As a crucial step, prove that the local versions of $\Phi$ constructed as so are smooth embeddings onto open sets.

5.) Then glue these local constructions of $\Phi$ by a smooth partition of unity and prove that it satisfies the desired properties stated in the theorem.

In step 5, once you're able to prove that the constructed $\Phi$ is an injective smooth immersion, in order to prove that it's a topological embedding just note that it can be restricted to open subsets of $\mathcal{P}_\delta$ on which it's equal to the local versions of $\Phi$ that you constructed in step 3. Since you proved in step 4 that the local versions of $\Phi$ are smooth embeddings onto open sets, the same will hold for $\Phi$ on these open subsets of $\mathcal{P}_\delta$. That with the injectivity of $\Phi$ then implies that $\Phi$ is a smooth embedding onto an open subset of $M$ (which is clearly a neighborhood of $\partial M$ since $\Phi \left(0,p \right)=p$). I wrote up a full proof on my website:

[https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hgrebnev/D&Writings/Z_PDF_Documents_I/Jack%20Lee%20Smooth%20Manifolds%20Notes.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ehgrebnev/D&Writings/Z_PDF_Documents_I/Jack%20Lee%20Smooth%20Manifolds%20Notes.pdf)

As is pointed out in the author's [errata](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/ISM/errata.pdf): the second part of the hint given in the book doesn't actually apply to this theorem because the integral curves of $N$ can never in fact hit the boundary. The reason for this is that if an integral curve of $N$ starting at a boundary point $p\in\partial M$ ever hit the boundary again, say at a point $q\in\partial M$, then $N$ would not be inward pointing at $q$.

Comment: lots of thanks. Very useful answer.